# Merging fields into Named Credentials for use with External Services and Flow

Tags: namedcredentials, external-services

I have an external REST API with an OpenAPI definition that I'd like to call from Salesforce via External Services + Flow. The external REST service needs a lot of extra stuff in the header for authentication.

I can connect with no problems in Apex and merge fields into Named Credential. How do I do this do in Flows with External Services using Named Credentials?

Comment: Out of the box, NC will generate the Authorization header with whatever options it's configured with. So your only solution is to use oAuth in NC as the auth protocol. You can then create a custom oAuth authentication provider and (if possible) force your authentication needs into this provider. You can then use NC with your Ext Svc.  Your stuff is not oAuth? That's what "force" means.. Likely this approach won't work for you.

Comment: Are you thinking of creating an Auth Provider Plugin as in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/authproviderplugin.htm or a 3rd party custom auth provider as sort of a middlelayer? I've been digging around the doc but can't really grasp the concepts. I believe I only need to add a couple of extra JWT claims to the Named Credential

Comment: Yes, give it a shot.

Comment: I've created an idea for [Bearer Token support for External Services](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000K5QdjUAF/bearer-token-support-for-external-services)